# Datatable items set to null upon commandLink action

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable, null, jsf-2.2

If I run the app and click the first `p:commandLink`, the `item` gets set as expected. When clicking another `p:commandLink` the previous one will be removed (null). The `h:commandLink` does not have that problem.

If I add `:theform:output` to the `update` parameter of the `p:commandLink`, the previously clicked item stops disappearing.

What is the reason for this behaviour?

**Env**

- Java 1.7.45
- Netbeans 7.4
- JSF Mojarra 2.2.4
- Primefaces 4.0

**Index.xhtml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <h:head>
        <title>Test</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form id="theform">
            <h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="tableBorder" id="tableWrapper">
                <h:dataTable value="#{xtestListBean.list}" var="item">
                    <h:column> 
                        <h:outputText value="#" styleClass="tableItem" />
                    </h:column>
                    <h:column> 
                        <h:commandLink 
                            value="#{item.name}" 
                            actionListener="#{xtestEntityBean.setItem(item)}">
                            <f:ajax render=":theform:tableWrapper" />
                        </h:commandLink>
                        <p:commandLink 
                            value="#{item.name}" 
                            actionListener="#{xtestEntityBean.setItem(item)}"
                            update=":theform:tableWrapper">
                        </p:commandLink>
                    </h:column>
                </h:dataTable>
            </h:panelGroup>
            <h:inputText value="#{xtestEntityBean.item.name}" size="40" id="output" />
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

**XtestListBean.java**

```
package beans;

import dto.Item;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class XtestListBean implements Serializable {

    private List<Item> list;

    public XtestListBean() {
        list = new ArrayList();
        list.add(new Item("Test 1"));
        list.add(new Item("Test 2"));
        list.add(new Item("Test 3"));
        list.add(new Item("Test 4"));
        list.add(new Item("Test 5"));
        list.add(new Item("Test 6"));
        list.add(new Item("Test 7"));
    }

    public List<Item> getList() {
        return list;
    }
}
```

**XtestEntityBean.java**

```
package beans;

import dto.Item;
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class XtestEntityBean implements Serializable {

    private Item item = new Item();

    public XtestEntityBean() {
    }

    public void setItem(Item item) {
        this.item = item;
    }

    public Item getItem() {
        return item;
    }

    public String getVersion() {
        return FacesContext.class.getPackage().getImplementationTitle()
                + " version "
                + FacesContext.class.getPackage().getImplementationVersion();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That only looks like so. It's just that the `<h:inputText value="#{xtestEntityBean.item.name}">` is also processed when the `<p:commandLink>` is invoked. In effects, the item's `name` is submitted with an empty/null value and that get reflected in the table. It's not the whole `Item` instance which became `null` or so.

How is this caused? Well, the `<f:ajax execute>` defaults to `@this`, meaning that only the current component (i.e. the command link) is processed during the form submit. However, the PrimeFaces equivalent, `<p:commandLink process>` defaults to `@form`, meaning that the entire parent form is processed during form submit, including that empty input field referring the item name.

If you explicitly set `<p:commandLink process>` to `@this`, the same as `<f:ajax execute>`'s default, then it should work as intented.

```
<p:commandLink 
    value="#{item.name}" 
    actionListener="#{xtestEntityBean.setItem(item)}"
    process="@this" update=":theform:tableWrapper">
</p:commandLink>
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and solution to the problem!